# Expected value of a min of a function of a random variable and a constant

Tags: probability, expectation

I am reading a paper on contracts and there was an expected value calculation which got me confused.

Consider the following primitives

- $\delta \in (0,1)$, an exogenous parameter
- $D$ a positive random variable with distribution $F$
- $S(q) = E[\min(q,D)]$ expected sales. The idea is that you are a retailer, order a quantity $q$ and can sell the min of what you ordered and what demand was.
  In the paper, it is shown that $S(q) = q(1 - F(q)) + \int_{0}^{q} y f(y) dy = q - \int_0^q F(y) dy$.
- $I(q)$ is expected leftover inventory $ = E[(q-D)^{+}] = q - S(q)$. Clearly the expected leftover inventory is $< q$, and probably $ > 0 $.

In the paper, they state that $$E[\min[I, \delta q]] = \int_{(1 - \delta)q}^{q} F(y) dy.$$

I am getting stuck understanding that relationship. Clearly on the function there is going to be some weight on $\delta q$ and some weight on $S(q)$, but I am getting stuck seeing exactly how this is derived.

EDIT: What I am trying to prove is the expectation of the $\min$. Also, $S(\cdot)$ and $I(\cdot)$ are both expectations. My apologies if this was not clear earlier.

Comment: In the third point, S(q) is defined as the random variable min(q,D), then equated to a number. In the fourth point I(q) is said to be the *expected* leftover inventory, that is, a number, then equated to the random variable (q-D)^+. Finally the identity to prove has a random variable on the LHS and a number on the RHS. Please explain.

Comment: Did I clarified. I was being a bit lax on where the expectation operator was being applied.

Comment: Still no definition of I available. If I is I(q) then min[I,δq] is nonrandom hence E[min[I,δq]]=min[I,δq]...

Answer (score 1):

"In the paper", "they" are probably trying to compute $E(X)$, where the random variable $X$ is $$X=\min((q-D)^+,\delta q).$$ 
Recall that, for every nonnegative random variable $\xi$, $$E(\xi)=\int_0^\infty P(\xi\geqslant x)\mathrm dx.$$
If $x\leqslant\delta q$, $[X\geqslant x]=[(q-D)^+\geqslant x]=[D\leqslant q-x]$. If $x\gt\delta q$, $[X\geqslant x]$ is empty. Hence, $$E(X)=\int_0^{\delta q}P(D\leqslant q-x)\mathrm dx=\int_{(1-\delta) q}^qP(D\leqslant x)\mathrm dx=\int_{(1-\delta) q}^qF(x)\mathrm dx.$$